# Swagger 2.0 uploading a file to SP Online that doesn't send the extra content through

Tags: rest, swagger-2.0

I'm hoping someone can point out my mistake here.
I have the following swagger definition which I use on swaggerhub that will upload a file to Sharepoint document library via the rest api

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "defaultDescription",
    "version" : "2",
    "title" : "defaultTitle"
  },
  "host" : "someSite.sharepoint.com",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/sites/ms/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('doc/test/tt')/Files/Add(url='{filename}',overwrite=true)" : {
      "post" : {
        "consumes" : [ "multipart/form-data" ],
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "in" : "formData",
          "name" : "upfile",
          "type" : "file",
          "required" : true,
          "description" : "The file to upload."
        },
        {             
          "in" : "path",
          "name" : "filename",
          "type" : "string",
          "required" : true
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "schema" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "description" : "Definition generated from Swagger Inspector"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is I can't open any files on SP because they're broken, and I believe I found the reason when I tested with a txt file.

I'll send a text file only containing `Sample text` bu when I open it on SP doc library it contains all the following as well

```
-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="myt.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Sample text
-------------------------------28947758029299--
```

Is the issue with my content type or should I use the parameter differently, I tried researching this but what I found just matched the original guid I found
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/

Comment: In what format does your Sharepoint API expects the file? HTTP protocol has several ways to upload files, `multipart/form-data` is just one of them, but it's probably not what Sharepoint expects.

Comment: If I use postman to upload the I see the file being sent with content-type text\plain and the file works once I try to open it SP side, but when I try to build the swagger with that as consume the swaggerhub throws an error: "Operations with parameters of "type: file" must include "multipart/form-data" in their "consumes" property"

The SP documentation didn't specify what the content-type is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

We came across a similar issue in our project.
The root cause is that Swagger 2.0 won't let you specify a different Content-Type for type file. You have to use multipart/form-data. See details here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/

To resolve this, you have to change the type from file to generic object. For example:

```
  paths:
  /sharepoint_upload/:
    post:
      description: "This will uploads a document to SharePoint."
      operationId: "uploadDocuments"
      consumes:
      - "application/octet-stream"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - name: "documentBody"
        in: "body"
        description: "The actual document"
        required: true
        schema:
          type: "object"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "OK - Your request was successfully completed."
        400:
```